# Visual Studio builds every time

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS2010, debugging as normal, and suddenly I notice that my code changes are having no effect. Moreover, even when I just type in some random crap and hit 'play', it still builds regardless. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check your Settings in the *Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run Section* making sure **Save all changes** is selected and **Launch Old Version** is not Selected.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is selected already. Was hoping it would be something simple like this, but I guess not :(

Comment: @DavidArcher I have seen something like this happen when you are referencing a Library Project or another Project and it is using an old version not the current one. I hav@e been able to correct by cleaning my solution and rebuilding each project in the proper order. You can also go to your Project settings and check your Reference Paths to make sure you are using the correct version of your assemblys

Comment: I thought "only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" should be checked, not?